# VirtoCommerce - Deleting a Large Catalog

Tags: virtocommerce

I have a catalog with 1,500+ items in it hosted on Azure in VC version 2.4.644.  When I attempt to delete it, the admin UI spins for 3-4 minutes, and then the deletion eventually fails with no error message.  This is on a database that has been scaled up to S2.  Deleting a catalog with a smaller number of items succeeds.

1. Is there a log somewhere I can review that might tell me why this is failing?
2. If I wanted to do this manually via SQL, is it "safe" to just delete the items from the dbo.Item table, or are there records in foreign tables that would be orphaned by this operation?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately catalog delete operation not optimal in current version and possible reason of you issue is a request timeout. We try to improve perfomance deletion in next release (aprox next week).

Delete throught native SQL not simple because Catalog contains hierarhical structures and more related tables without cascade deletion (because some tables contains self references MS SQL limitation).